# sql server query returning null

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader

**I am new to asp.net and sql server** i wrote a code to set my model and i just need a row so i wrote this code:

My model

```
public class FullPackages
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Package Type")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; } 
    public int AllowedSMS { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Time Span in Days")]
    public int? TimeSpan { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

My Method

```
    public ActionResult PackageDetails(int id = 0)
    {
        string sqlString = "select top 1 tblPackages.*, tblPackageTypes.Name from tblPackages join tblPackageTypes on tblPackages.TypeId = tblPackageTypes.Id where tblPackages.Id = "+id;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnxn); // cnxn is defined
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, con);
        SqlDataReader dsr;
        FullPackages package = new FullPackages();


            con.Open();

            dsr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  // this returns null value

                package.Id = dsr.GetInt32(0);
                package.TypeId = dsr.GetInt32(1);
                package.TypeName = dsr.GetString(5);
                package.AllowedSMS = dsr.GetInt32(2);
                package.TimeSpan = dsr.IsDBNull(3) ? 0 : dsr.GetInt32(3);
                package.Price = dsr.GetDecimal(4);
            con.Close();

        return View(package);
    }
```

when i remove `top 1` from the sqlString it returns the values from the database but when i keep `top 1` it returns null.And when i check the same sql with `top 1` in sql server Mgmt Studio it returns single row.. Why is it so?? Please help me....

Comment: I guess this is not the working code, because ID is defined as int but is appended to the SQL Select string as if it were string.

Comment: @EmmadKareem no it works fine. i just appended the value of int to string. Also when i remove `top 1` the code works fine.

Comment: A number appended to a string results in string.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS, yes but only when appended with .ToString()

Comment: i suggest you open console and try it.

Comment: @EmmadKareem thats ok but if the query is `select top 1 * from tblPackages` then also the problem is same. Please help with this

Comment: Have you tried like this : select top (1) with ties .......(your query)

Comment: Maybe your connection failed to open. You'd normally code something like this: try {con.open; SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();reader.Read();while(reader.Read()) {...}} catch {...} - Also your code does not include the *reader.Read* part. In addition, if you want to read 1 row only use ExecuteScalar.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: I think you are correct with the `reader.Read()`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this instead of your code:

```
string sqlString = "select top 1 tblPackages.*, tblPackageTypes.Name from tblPackages join tblPackageTypes on tblPackages.TypeId = tblPackageTypes.Id where tblPackages.Id = " + id;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnxn); // cnxn is defined 

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, con); 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        sda.Fill(dt);
        FullPackages package = new FullPackages();

        package.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]); 
        package.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][1]);
        package.AllowedSMS = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][2]); 
        package.TimeSpan = !DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows[0][3]) ? Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][3]) : 0;
        package.Price = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][4]);
```

Comment: though the coding pattern is changed. This helped